# Flutter : can't get all response body from get request

Tags: flutter, response, get-request

I have get request in Flutter app, when I test the request in postman I get all data, something like this :

```
{
"result":{
   "name" : "somename",
   "images":[
      "test.jpg",
      "test2.jpg"
    ],
   "sizes":[
     {
       "id": 1,
       "value" : 5
     },
     {
       "id": 2,
       "value" : 15
     }
    ]
 }
}
```

I call data and print them like this without using models:

```
var data = json.decode(response.body);
print(data['result']['name']);
print(data['result']['images']);
print(data['result']['sizes']);
```

it is print all things expect last one.

where must be the mistake?

Comment: Are you working on the backend yourself?

Comment: @Roaa no I just worked with front end, they gave me api

Comment: Try to check the Postman code, you'll find it on the right side, and select **HTTP dart** , then inspect it

Comment: Is your problem with console print? because the print function in flutter has a character limit. use debugger instead and see if you have full data.

Comment: @YoussefElmoumen many thanks, I found it there, add this line after link , "?sizesView=true"

Answer (score 0):

Solved, by adding `"?sizesView = true"` to the link

```
final response = await http.get(path +'?sizesView = true'):
```

Answer (score -1):

you should get the index of the last one because it is in a dictionary not a list do this:

```
print(data['result']['sizes'][0]['id']) // it will get the first index of the sizes list and then get the id key
```

or you can creat a model of list to get the indexes of your list